# What is the Order of Execution of data types?

Tags: solidity, remix, data-types

I have created and deployed(Remix) a simple contract to understand better data types. When I deploy contract, I see that data types are not in the order inside the contract. Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.7;

contract DataTypes {
    uint public uintNumber = 9;
    int public intNumber = -68;
    uint8 public uint8Number = 17;
    bool public myBool = true;
    address public myAddress = msg.sender;
    bytes32 public myBytes32 = "hello byte";
    string public myString = "hello string";
}
```

And here is the situation after deployment. I expect to see "uint" first, but somehow "int" is coming first and rest is in a complete different order. Do you know the reason for this? Is it something related to Remix or something related to Solidity?

[image: Contract view after deployment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it something related to Remix or something related to Solidity?

Remix just arranges them in the UI in alphanumerical order.

There is no relation to which storage slots each variable inhabits.

I believe the sorting is done in `txhelper.ts`, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/2b5b7f49b6836c0b7777ccebe599257f38240531/libs/remix-lib/src/execution/txHelper.ts#L46), where each of your variables generates a getter function, which is considered constant. The important line of code is:

```
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
```

Comment: I just realized my idiot mistake. True, it is in alphabetical order. And thank you very much for providing deeper information.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity Compiler automatically rearrange EVM slot wise.In EVM 1 slot size is 32 bytes. If you want to understand how to solidity compiler arrange the storage slot then read the [solidity docs.](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/internals/layout_in_storage.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for information on EVM slot sizes. That was a topic I didnt know about, I have checked the link you shared and I will further study on it.